# Modify a value of an object of another object, using a variable to point to the requested property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Firstly I want to apologize for using crude snippets of code, I'm not really great at shortening my code to show problems and keep in mind this is ***vanilla ES5 javascript***, but I'll try my best, so here goes:

I want to be able to modify a value of a property in an object inside another object, which I know is something like this in my case.

`jsonFile[0].firstObject.secondObject.property = newValue`

And if I want to bake this into a function that I can reuse at different point in my code by using variables to point to the property, it would be something like this.

`jsonFile[0][firstObjectPointer][secondObjectPointer][propertyPointer] = newValue`

But as I can only pass one value into the function when I need 3, I have chosen to use an array that stores information I need: the file name, ***the property pointer***, and the new value. the following is a real example I would use:

```
// [0] file name - [1] data to change - [2] new data

["something.txt", "basicInfo.name", "Meliodas"]
```

As I store the pointers separated by ".", I separate the values and store them in a new array, ***this is where my problem come into play***, I need a way to place the pointers (which can vary in number, there can be two like in the example or even 5), i have tried something with a for loop, but it doesn't actually work:

*dataPoint is the array that stores the separated pointers, dataToUpdate is the main JSON to be updated, in theory, it would run until the last pointer, then insert the new value at that point*

```js
for (i = 0; i < dataPoint.length; i += 1) {
        console.log('now inside the for loop');
        if (i < (dataPoint.length - 1)) {
            dataToUpdate[0] = dataToUpdate[0][dataPoint[i]];
            console.log(dataToUpdate);
        } else if (i === (dataPoint.length - 1)) {
            dataToUpdate[dataPoint] = newData;
        } else {
            console.log('nothing has actually worked');
        }
    }
```

Can anyone give any insight into what i can do? have I explained the problem well enough? Literally any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You know JS functions can take multiple parameters, right? Looks like you might be after something like Lodash's [`_.set()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set)

Comment: I did not know that... that does help a fair bit in simplifying a lot of code, thank you

Comment: ._set() would be perfect, but my project is for class extra credit, and we cannot use external frameworks, and we must host on a server such as apache or nginx, so it rules out using nodejs

Comment: @Phil, that solved my problem, thank you for redirecting my question!